# Where should scanner go in this program?

Tags: java

I'm working on a program that takes the input of two numbers and then does some different calculations. I have my TwoNumbers class with several different methods to calculate sum, distance, average, etc.

Should I put the scanner in this class, or should I put it in the Main method?

I know this is really basic but I've only been learning java for a couple weeks and I'm having a hard time finding how this should be done/how to get the input to correlate to my instance variables and firstNumber and secondNumber

```
public class TwoNumbers{

private double firstNumber;
private double secondNumber;

public double getSum()
{
    double sum = firstNumber + secondNumber;
    return sum;
}

public double getDifference()
{
    double difference = firstNumber - secondNumber;
    return difference;
}

public double getProduct()
{
    double product = firstNumber - secondNumber;
    return product;
}

public double getAverage()
{
    double average = (firstNumber + secondNumber) / 2;
    return average;
}

public double getDistance()
{
    double distance = Math.abs(firstNumber - secondNumber);
    return distance;
}

public double getMax()
{
    double maximum = Math.max(firstNumber, secondNumber);
    return maximum;
}

public double getMin()
{
    double minimum = Math.min(firstNumber, secondNumber);
    return minimum;
}
}
```

Comment: You have no accessors for `firstNumber` and `secondNumber`.  At this point, you're using reflection in `main` (where `Scanner` would live) to hydrate those fields.

Answer (score 4):

Each class should follow the [single responsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). Your `TwoNumbers` class should only work with the `double` numbers and perform operations on them, nothing more. Providing the `double` numbers for this class should be in the client, and also the ability to provide the numbers, which means that the client may define the `Scanner` or another way to provide the data.

Answer (score 1):

The class you have displayed, the TwoNumbers class, should have no user input in it as it should encapsulate the concept of two numbers and two numbers only. It should be written in such a way that it can be used with a Scanner program or with a GUI program without having to change it. Thus the UI should be in main or in another class.

Answer (score 1):

You would probably want to make a constructor for the class, and within the constructor pass the variables you want. This would mean that you get your input from somewhere else, IE the main method or some other means.

```
public TwoNumbers(double num1, double num2){

    firstNumber = num1;
    secondNumber = num2;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
For example:
public double getSum(firstnumber, secondnumber) // <-- you need pass in the value
{
    double sum = firstNumber + secondNumber;
    return sum;
}
/*
 * somewhere in the main or another method you can delare the first number / 2nd number
 * for example:
*/
public void static main (String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("enter first number");
    firstnumber = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("enter first number");
    secondnumber = input.nextInt();
    }
```

After that all you need to do is just calling the method you want to pass the number to.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a constructor in `TwoNumbers`:

```
public class TwoNumbers {

    private double firstNumber;
    private double secondNumber;

    public TwoNumbers(double firstNumber, double secondNumber){
        this.firstNumber = firstNumber;
        this.secondNumber = secondNumber;
    }
}
```

Then in some other Class, you can have your scanner:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter firstNumber");
        double firstNumber = scanner.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter secondNumber");
        double secondNumber = scanner.nextDouble();

        TwoNumbers obj = new TwoNumbers(firstNumber, secondNumber);

        //Call methods from TwoNumbers
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Really the code would work if you put the scanner in the main class or in the `TwoNumbers` class. The best practice way of doing this would be to place your scanner and any other input/output code in you main class, and the processing/calculation code in another class. Which one you choose will be based on your application, but most of the time you will have the scanner in the main class. So...

```
public class Driver {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s;
        while((s = in.nextLine()) != "stop"){
            TwoNumbers.sum(Double.parseDouble(s.split(" ")[0]), Double.parseDouble(s.split(" ")[1]));
        }
        in.close();
    }
}

public class TwoNumbers{
        public static double sum(double a, double b){
            return a+b;
        }
    }
}
```